# Jquery incorporate a second .click option inside a working if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, var

I got a question? I got this code, the thing that I want to achieve is to incorporate a click2 on just the 2nd click of the if statement? Is that possible or do I sound like a weirdo?

It's because I used a .slidetoggle but when I separate a .click(close button) script, it messes up the toggle mechanism...

If its not possible, is there any option?

http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/11/

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');

    if ( clicked ) {
        alert('second time');
    }else{
        alert('first time');
    }

    $(this).data('clicked', !clicked);
});
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm not really following - your example has two buttons... do you want the second button to do the same action that the first button does the second time it was clicked?

Comment: Exactly! just the second click...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by having a counter variable like this.

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#click').click(function(){
    clickCount++;
    alert(clickCount);
    if(clickCount ==2)
       alert("Achieved Second click");
});
```

Comment: What happens when the user slicks more than 2 times? Doesn't look like your script accounts for that...

Comment: Hi apaul, 
He wanted to arrive at just the second click of that element. So i gave it in a simple way.